# Reduce color list to more common colors - Python

Tags: python, colors, mapping, grouping, rgb

I have a list of *1723* colors in hex codes (I could also turn them to RGB but the issue is not the format of the color), like this: `cols = ['#A62E2E', '#D99036', '#D9C27E', '#D9AB9A', '#592C22']`.

I'm trying to reduce the amount of colors in that list to 1/10th of what it already is by grouping similar colors. So in my example, the *1723* colors will be mapped to 172.

I have already checked these posts: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747841/group-similar-hex-codes-in-php), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994269/how-to-group-rgb-or-hex-color-codes-to-bigger-sets-of-color-groups), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496971/map-colors-in-image-to-closest-member-of-a-list-of-colors-in-python), [post4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242194/python-find-the-closest-color-to-a-color-from-giving-list-of-colors), [post5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366981/python-pil-finding-nearest-color-rounding-colors) but they are not exactly what I want. Basically I want to create the groups dynamically from the color list I have and not a preexisting one.

It would also be very beneficial for me if I could keep as much variety as possible so preferably id like as different groups as possible.

**What I've already tried:**

The only solution I've found so far is a function from a stackoverflow post

```
def closest_color(rgb):
r, g, b = rgb
color_diffs = []
for color in nodes['Rgb']:
    cr, cg, cb = color
    color_diff = sqrt(abs(r - cr)**2 + abs(g - cg)**2 + abs(b - cb)**2)
    color_diffs.append((color_diff, color))
return min(color_diffs)[1]
```

Which basically gives you the closest color to your agument from a list, but this requires a preexisting list of colors and does the mapping.

The way I'm thinking it could be done is iterate over my list, leaving the current element out and calling this function for the rest of the list and grouping the 2 colors, then doing that until I have only 172 colors. However im not sure if that will give me enough distinct colors or how to group the 2 colors I get for that matter.

I don't know enough about colors to figure out a way of doing that without messing my color range.

Comment: You could write a function that grouped colors that only differ by a specified amount so for example `#FFFFFF` would group with `#FFFFFE` because they only differ by 1. You could set the tolerances to whatever you like and create it dynamically.

Comment: Research "k-means" or "clustering".

Comment: I know about k-means and clustering but I already have the list of colors and I'd like to find a concrete solution if possible, also I dont think I can compare colors by comparing the differences between hexes as a hex works like a tuple of 3 numbers and not a continuous number, am i Wrong ?

Comment: You could convert to HSL and perform clustering on those 3 dimensions

Comment: @mozway Will that be accurate but diverse enough you think ?

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392276/17457042) before working with RBG values.

Comment: @Konstantinos I guess the diversity will depend on the original sample

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that clusters the colors using `scipy`. Please note that [using RBG is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392276/17457042), and you would need to transform your data to a [uniform color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_appearance_model)) before clustering. The transformation in the example is included as a placeholder: it is not really useful since YIQ is not a uniform color space. There are [different](https://www.colour-science.org/) [modules](https://pypi.org/project/colour/) that can be used to perform the transformation.

The final list is in `rgb_clusters`.

```py
import colorsys
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2
from numpy.random import random_sample

n_colors = 1732
n_seek = n_colors // 10
rgb_data = random_sample((n_colors, 3))
# Let's change from RGB to another colour space. YIQ is not a
# good choice: a uniform colour space should be
# used (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_appearance_model).
# in this example I use YIQ for its simplicity.
yiq_data = [colorsys.rgb_to_yiq(*rgb) for rgb in rgb_data]
yiq_clusters, mapping = kmeans2(yiq_data, n_seek, minit='++')
rgb_clusters = [colorsys.yiq_to_rgb(*yiq) for yiq in yiq_clusters]

# Let's see the results graphically
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(*zip(*rgb_clusters), c=rgb_clusters, s=20, label="centroids")
ax.scatter(*zip(*rgb_data), c=rgb_data, s=6, label="data")
for o_data, idx_cluster in zip(rgb_data, mapping):
    cluster = rgb_clusters[idx_cluster]
    ax.plot(*zip(o_data, cluster), c=cluster)
ax.set_xlabel("R")
ax.set_ylabel("G")
ax.set_zlabel("B")
plt.legend()
```

Result:
[image: Result of clustering]